# Why is my android phone portscanning my PC?

Tags: windows

I have bitdefender whining about my PC being portscanned.
The logs show that it is coming from my android phone (which has static address).

[image]

Is that normal?
How can i figure out the app that is doing this?

Edit:I just thought, should this be posted to the Android cousin of superuser?

Comment: It’s much more likely your firewall software is interpreting this wrong, on purpose. Does it display any more information on this “incident”?

Comment: Unfortunately no more information. I have several apps that might be connecting to my pc, like remote controll aps etc.

Comment: This question was migrated from super user. I had already created a question on this forum. Please feel free to remove either of them.